# Passing Python function to Boost C++

Tags: python, c++, boost, function-pointers

I'm trying to learn about Boost functions. I want to pass a Python function to a C++ module wrapped using Boost Python. I followed the example given [here](http://bfroehle.com/2011/07/boost-python-and-boost-function/) and modified it to accept functions that take an input argument and return some output. Here's my code:

```
typedef double (op_t)(double);
boost::function<op_t> op;

double defaultOperator(double t) {
  return t;
}

void setOperator(boost::python::object obj) {
  op = obj;
}

double callOperator(double t) {
  return op(t);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(op1) {
  op = &defaultOperator;

  def("setOperator", &setOperator);
  def("callOperator", &callOperator);
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get an error in my `setOperator` function that says `cannot convert ‘boost::python::api::object’ to ‘double’ in return`. The code works if I replace the typedef line with `typedef void (op_t)(double);` and change `callOperator` to return void. This allows me to pass Python functions that can operate on arguments but do not return anything.

What is wrong in my code? How should I correct it to pass a Python function that returns a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching and some trial & error, I managed to modify my code so that it works. I had to create a wrapper struct for the Boost Python object, which included a `operator()` method, so that the wrapped object could then be cast as a Boost Function before being assigned to the `op` variable. Here's the modified code:

```
struct op_wrapper_t {

  op_wrapper_t( object callable ) : _callable( callable ) {}

  double operator()(double t) {
    return extract<double>(_callable(t));
  }

  object _callable;
};

void setOperator(object obj) {
  op = boost::function<double (double)>( op_wrapper_t(obj) );
}
```

I followed a similar procedure as the one in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179345/python-method-to-boost-function). However, I still don't understand why no such wrapper/casting is needed for functions that return void.