# Can I pass a python function as a function pointer to a function bound through Boost.Python?

Tags: python, c++, c, boost

So if I have a function:

```
void foo(void(*fn)()) {
  fn();
}
```

Which I've added to my Boost.Python module:

```
boost::python::def(&foo);
```

Is there any way I can make something like this work in my python script:

```
def my_fn():
  print 'hello'

foo(my_fn)
```

Comment: Unsure about it, but try this: [Passing Python function to Boost C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451863/passing-python-function-to-boost-c).