# Convert Python function to C++, via Boost Python, for use as a callback

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

In general what is the recommended way to pass a Python function through Boost-Python for use later in C++ code (i.e. as a callback in a C++ object)?

More specifically, I have a C++ class `FooCPP` that I've successfully exposed to Python via Boost-Python; the user interacts with the Python class `Foo` that runs the C++ counterpart under the hood. Contrived example:

```
# Foo.py

from foo_base import FooBase

class Foo(FooBase):
    ...

def callback(val=42.):
    return val

foo = Foo()
foo.run(callback)
```

And the Boost Python bindings:

```
// foo_bindings.cpp

#include "foo.hpp"
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace bp =  boost::python;

FooPython::Run(const bp::object& py_callback)
    // TODO: Do something with the python callback to make it a C++ function!
    std::function<double(double)> cpp_callback;
    FooCPP::Run(cpp_callback);
)

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo_base){
    bp::class_<FooPython>("FooBase")
    .def("run", &FooPython::Run)
    ;
}
```

So how can I address the TODO comment in foo_bindings.cpp?

I've gone through a number of related SO questions -- e.g. [pass python function to boost c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451863/passing-python-function-to-boost-c) and [sending py function as boost function arg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049533/sending-python-function-as-boost-function-argument) -- and I'm familiar with the [Boost-Python docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/doc/v2/callbacks.html), but have not found a good solution/explanation. Thanks in advance!

Notes: C++11, boost v1.58.0, ubuntu 16.04

#### Update

I may have just found a solution, where I can implement a functor in foo_bindings.cpp, e.g.,

```
struct PythonCallback {
public:
    PythonCallback(bp::object cb_func) : cb_func_(cb_func) {}
    double operator() (const double& val) {
        // Call the callback function in python
        return cb_func_(val);
    }
private:
    bp::object cb_func_;
};
```

But then what should the `FooCPP::Run` signature be? I.e. what type is defined for the `cpp_callback` passed in?

And does the `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` code need to change for this callback functor?

Comment: Do you just need to do this for a single function type (eg: double(double)) or something more generic?

Comment: @SeanMcAllister if there is a solution for a more generic callback function that takes in other args -- e.g. `callback(x, y=42., z=True)` -- that'd be great to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a functor in foo_bindings.cpp, where the callback is invoked with [call](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/doc/v2/call.html#call-spec):

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/call.hpp>

struct PythonCallback : {
public:
    PythonCallback(PyObject* func) : cb_(func) {}
    double operator() (const double& value) {
        // Call the callback function in python
        return boost::python::call<double>(cb_, value);
    }
private:
    PyObject* cb_;
};
```