# Passing a function as function argument in Boost.Python

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-python, std-function

I have a C++ function `ExecuteFunction` that takes as input another function `f`.

I would like to expose `ExecuteFunction` in Python with Boost.Python, and call it from Python with either Python functions or other C++ functions as arguments. I've found plenty of information on how to pass Python functions to `ExecuteFunction` [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049533/sending-python-function-as-boost-function-argument)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613315/exporting-c-function-with-stdfunction-argument-to-python-using-boost-python)[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613315/exporting-c-function-with-stdfunction-argument-to-python-using-boost-python), but can't figure out how to specify a plain C++ function as argument.

Here is what I'm currently doing:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

typedef std::function<int(int)> Function;

int ExecuteFunction(int x, Function f) {
  return f(x);
};

int Half(int x) {
  return x / 2;
};

struct Square {
  int operator()(int x) const {
    return x * x;
  };
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Test) {
  boost::python::def("ExecuteFunction", ExecuteFunction);
  boost::python::def("Half", Half);
  boost::python::class_<Square>("Square")
    .def("__call__", &Square::operator());
};
```

On the Python side I would like to do the following:

```py
import Test

def Double(x):
    return x * 2

a = Test.ExecuteFunction(2, Test.Half)
b = Test.ExecuteFunction(2, Test.Square())
c = Test.ExecuteFunction(2, Double)
```

But the calls to `Test.ExecuteFunction` fail with the following tracebacks respectively:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Test.ExecuteFunction(int, Boost.Python.function)
did not match C++ signature:
    ExecuteFunction(int, std::function<int (int)>)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Test.ExecuteFunction(int, Square)
did not match C++ signature:
    ExecuteFunction(int, std::function<int (int)>)
```

```
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Test.ExecuteFunction(int, function)
did not match C++ signature:
    ExecuteFunction(int, std::function<int (int)>)
```

I'm not really interested in calling `Half` and `Square` on the Python side (although being able to do so would be nice). I would be satisfied with being able to specify the right argument to `ExecuteFunction`. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell exposed C++ functions are always converted to a Python equivalent when constructed/invoked in Python. Hence `ExecuteFunction` should take as input a `boost::python::object`, not a `std::function`, even if you only intend to pass C++ functions as argument. You can then call the function and retrieve its return value with `boost::python::call`.

The following wound up working:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int ExecuteFunctionWrapper(int x, const boost::python::object& f) {
  return boost::python::call<int>(f.ptr(), x);
};

int Half(int x) {
  return x / 2;
};

struct Square {
  int operator()(int x) const {
    return x * x;
  };
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Test) {
  boost::python::def("ExecuteFunction", ExecuteFunctionWrapper);
  boost::python::def("Half", Half);
  boost::python::class_<Square>("Square")
    .def("__call__", &Square::operator());
};
```

```py
import Test

def Double(x):
    return x * 2

a = Test.ExecuteFunction(4, Test.Half)
b = Test.ExecuteFunction(4, Test.Square())
c = Test.ExecuteFunction(4, Double)
print(a, b, c)
```